# Flutter - Unable to curve edges of sliding_up_panel

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm confused as to why the borderRadius of [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) is not responding at all.

Here is my code...

```
SlidingUpPanel(
    minHeight: 10.h,
    collapsed: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: radius, // this is working
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    child: SignUpHeader(),
   ),
   panelBuilder: (scrollController) =>
      buildSlidingPanel(scrollController: scrollController),
   body: Container(some code),
   borderRadius: radius, // this is not working
  )
```

The radius used above is this...

```
final BorderRadiusGeometry radius = BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
    topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
  );
```

I want to get rid of the white background in the following image...
[image]

Comment: Try wrapping your ``SlidingUpPanel`` widget with the ``ClipRRect()`` widget and set it's ``borderRadius`` property.

Comment: But according to the documentation, SlidingUpPanel should be the root widget...

Comment: It however did solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

you can use clipRReact as a parent of Slidinguppanel or if you don,t want to use it

you can set the color of the slidinguppanel as the same color as the scaffold

but using clipRReact will be better